# PHP File Writing shows Empty Screen

Tags: php

I am trying to write some content infile but it is showing blank screen

```
$write = fopen("newfile.txt", "r");
fwrite($write, "John Doe");
```

Here is my code , what is the problem ,

Comment: Put write permission instead of read permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got the wrong action

Change the 'r' to 'w'

```
$write = fopen("newfile.txt", "w");
fwrite($write, "John Doe");
```

But i would recommend you to handle with `die`

```
<?php
$write = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($write, "John Doe");
fclose($write);
?>
```

**Update :** As the questioner wants to append with old content

Then you need set with `a` in your `fopen`

```
<?php
$write = fopen("newfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($write, "John Doe");
fclose($write);
?>
```

Note : It is better to use `\n` at the end of your content as it will break the line and take it to next line, else the content will continue one the previous line itself

I would recommend you to read on php [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: There's no need to die. fopen return false of failure.

Comment: Oh god, it is just replacing my enter content to new content. how can i add the content below to the old text

Comment: then you need to append with your old data

Comment: @user4767557 : Updated my answer to append with old content.

Answer (score 1):

use

`$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a')`

example

```
$myFile = "newfile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "John Doe 1\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "John Doe 2\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

output

```
Floppy Jalopy
Pointy Pinto
John Doe 1
John Doe 2
```